# Export all result rows

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

Take this query for example

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   C_BPARTNER.NAME,
   IEU01_DIVISIONAR.NAME,
   IEU01_SPECIALZTNAR.NAME,
   IEU01_UNIMASTER_TRL.NAME,
   IEU01_COLLEGE_TRL.NAME
FROM C_BPARTNER
LEFT OUTER JOIN IEU01_STUDENTMASTER
ON C_BPARTNER.C_BPARTNER_ID = IEU01_STUDENTMASTER.C_BPARTNER_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN REPIEULIVE.IEU01_COLLEGE_TRL
ON IEU01_STUDENTMASTER.IEU01_COLLEGE_ID = IEU01_COLLEGE_TRL.IEU01_COLLEGE_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN IEU01_DIVISIONAR
ON IEU01_STUDENTMASTER.IEU01_DIVISIONAR_ID = IEU01_DIVISIONAR.IEU01_DIVISIONAR_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN REPIEULIVE.IEU01_SPECIALZTNAR
ON IEU01_STUDENTMASTER.IEU01_SPECIALZTNAR_ID = IEU01_SPECIALZTNAR.IEU01_SPECIALZTNAR_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN REPIEULIVE.IEU01_UNIMASTER_TRL
ON IEU01_STUDENTMASTER.IEU01_UNIMASTER_ID = IEU01_UNIMASTER_TRL.IEU01_UNIMASTER_ID

WHERE C_BPARTNER.IEU01_ISMEMBER = 'Y'
```

When I replace the columns with `Count(*)` to see the number of rows, I get `221077` rows, which what I suspect
[image]

But when I export the result, it exports `220516` rows, which is exactly the number of rows when I count using the developer **Count Rows** function
[image]

Why the numbers are different? Is there a mistake in the query?
I thought this happens when the result is big, so I tried a simple `select count(*) from C_BPARTNER`, it matches with **Count Rows** functions

Comment: Did someone change contents of table(s) involved in your query (deleted some of them, perhaps?) in between your "select count(*)" and "count rows"?

Comment: because there's a distinct in your initial query, not in the count. And distinct count(*) is equal to count(*). What you need is count (distinct ...)

Comment: @Littlefoot , no actually I'm doing this several times and it's the same

Comment: @gsalem, yes that was the issue, it matched when I removed (distinct) Thank you for your help.